# How to create this type dynamic tab structure in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic4, android-tabs

I want to create a this type of tab structure in Ionic 4 using dynamic JSON array.
The problem i'm facing is that, if the number of tabs is greater than 5, then i want to add that extra tabs in menu like structure. How to achieve this? 
Any help would be appreciated
[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I h've achieved this...